# Applescript: set allFiles to every file of entire contents of Doesnt work on subfolders?

Tags: applescript

Im using a script to batch convert a bunch of m4v´s to a set framesize, and im using this script. However, if theres a folder inside my parentfolder (Omkodning) with its own folder, it doesn't look inside that folder. Since my heriarchi is deeper then just one folder, this script isn't working all the way. How do I change it to search the entire content of my parent folder (Omkodning) ?

```
--on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
with timeout of (720 * 60) seconds
tell application "Finder"
    --Get all m4v files that have no label color yet, meaning it hasn’t been processed
    set allFiles to every file of entire contents of ("FIRSTHD:Users:jerry:Desktop:Omkodning" as alias) whose ((name extension is "m4v") and label index is 0)
    --Repeat for all files in above folder
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in allFiles
        set currentFile to (item i of allFiles)
        try
            --Set to gray label to indicate processing
            set label index of currentFile to 7
            --Assemble original and new file paths
            set origFilepath to quoted form of POSIX path of (currentFile as alias)
            set newFilepath to (characters 1 thru -5 of origFilepath as string) & "mp4'"
            --Start the conversion
            set shellCommand to "nice /Applications/HandBrakeCLI -i " & origFilepath & " -o " & newFilepath & " -e ffmpeg4 -b 1200 -a 1 -E faac -B 160 -R 29.97 -f mp4 –crop 0:0:0:0 crf 24 -w 640 -l 480  ;"
            do shell script shellCommand
            --Set the label to green in case file deletion fails
            set label index of currentFile to 6
            --Remove the old file
            set shellCommand to "rm -f " & origFilepath
            do shell script shellCommand
        on error errmsg
            --Set the label to red to indicate failure
            set label index of currentFile to 2
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
end timeout
--end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed This and it seems to work now.

```
and label index is 0)
```